# Add attachment in existing Jira Issue

Tags: java, jersey, jira, jira-rest-java-api

Please Help me to attach a file in existing issue using Jira Java REST Client.

my java code

```
FileInputStream fileStreamPath=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\eswaranr\\Downloads\\Complete Program.doc");
final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("CPS-150", pm);
restClient.getIssueClient().addAttachment(pm, issue.getAttachmentsUri(), fileStreamPath, "Complete Program.doc");
```

my Pom.xml

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joda.time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>Jira-rest-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-m02</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.bytecode</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
        <systemPath>D:\JIRA\api\jersey-multipart-1.12.jar</systemPath>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet</groupId>
        <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Jul 11, 2013 12:44:57 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter$RequestEntityWriterImpl <init>
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and MIME media type multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary_1_1319874444_1373526897746 was not found
Jul 11, 2013 12:44:57 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter$RequestEntityWriterImpl <init>
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONWithPaddingProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
```

I dont know what I want to do to overcome this issue.
Can any one tell me what exactly I missed in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed my pom.xml dependencies with follwoing pom.xml and its working fine

https://maven-us.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/groups/public/com/atlassian/jira/jira-rest-java-client/1.1-m02/jira-rest-java-client-1.1-m02.pom